# How to create a window in a dataset in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to create a window using create_windows of ForecastML package for a dataset having a Timestamp 3-20-2017 05:56:35 to 3-20-2017 08:03:27 using the code:

```
windows <- forecastML::create_windows(data_train, window_length = 0,  
         # 0 spans from window_start to window_stop, 
         window_start = as.POSIXct(lubridate::mdy_hms("2017-03-20 07:53:32"), tz = "UTC"), 
         window_stop = as.POSIXct(lubridate::mdy_hms("2017-03-20 07:58:32"), tz = "UTC")
         )
```

I am getting an error

> Error in if (!window_start >= data_start) { :    missing value where
> TRUE/FALSE needed

Can anybody please tell me for the above mentioned timestamp what value should I give to window_start and window_stop for creating a window of length 0?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `mdy_hms` is wrong. try changing it to `ymd_hms`.

Comment: You don't need to use both `as.POSIXct` and `lubridate` function `mdy_hms`. Use either one of them. And yes, it should be `ymd_hms`, `lubridate::mdy_hms("2017-03-20 07:53:32")` gives you `NA`.